# Resuming interrupted upload using Google drive v3 C# sdk

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I want to resume interrupted resumable upload using Google Drive v3 C# SDK.
The reason why I want this is to create resumable upload in Restful Web API.
There is google drive api instance in this RestAPI, so this is relaying chunk data from client program to google drive.
As you know, client program cannot upload whole file data at one time to Web API, so we need to resume interrupted resumable upload.

So my plan is here.

- First, we need to create upload session and receive Session URI.
- Second, Create Upload instance every time from returned URI and add chunk data.
- Third, repeat 2nd process until EOF.

For this, I made test code, but it does not work at all.

```
var uploadStream = new System.IO.FileStream(UploadFileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open,
            System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
var insert = service.Files.Create(new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File { Name = title }, uploadStream, ContentType);

Uri uploadUri = insert.InitiateSessionAsync().Result;

int chunk_size = ResumableUpload.MinimumChunkSize;
while (uploadStream.Length != uploadStream.Position)
{
    byte[] temp = new byte[chunk_size];
    uploadStream.Read(temp, 0, temp.Length);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(temp);

    ResumableUpload resume_uploader = ResumableUpload.CreateFromUploadUri(uploadUri, stream);

    resume_uploader.ChunkSize = chunk_size;
    IUploadProgress ss =  resume_uploader.Resume();

    Console.WriteLine("Uploaded " + ss.BytesSent.ToString());
}
```

Frankly, I expected to receive 308 Resume Incomplete Code, but the result is different.

"Invalid request.  According to the Content-Range header, the final size of the upload is 262144 byte(s). This does not match the expected size of 1193188 byte(s), which was specified in an earlier request."

This means that I need to create code that resumes interrupted resumable upload using Google Drive C# SDK.

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I solved issue. Exact code is below. Actually, I could not find any source code on Google, so I was so sad. Every developer who wants to solve this issue, use my code please. Hope you are fine. :)

```
    public static async Task<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> UploadSync(DriveService driveService, string filepath)
    {
        string destfilename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);

        List<string> parents = new List<string>();

        parents.Add("root");
        // Prepare the JSON metadata
        string json = "{\"name\":\"" + destfilename + "\"";
        if (parents.Count > 0)
        {
            json += ", \"parents\": [";
            foreach (string parent in parents)
            {
                json += "\"" + parent + "\", ";
            }
            json = json.Remove(json.Length - 2) + "]";
        }
        json += "}";
        Debug.WriteLine(json);

        Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File uploadedFile = null;
        try
        {
            System.IO.FileInfo info = new System.IO.FileInfo(filepath);

            ulong fileSize = (ulong)info.Length;

            var uploadStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filepath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

            var insert = driveService.Files.Create(new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File { Name = destfilename, Parents = new List<string> { "root" } }, uploadStream, "application/octet-stream");

            Uri uploadUri = insert.InitiateSessionAsync().Result;

            int chunk_size = ResumableUpload.MinimumChunkSize;
            int bytesSent = 0;
            while (uploadStream.Length != uploadStream.Position)
            {
                byte[] temp = new byte[chunk_size];
                int cnt = uploadStream.Read(temp, 0, temp.Length);
                if (cnt == 0)
                    break;

                HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uploadUri);

                httpRequest.Method = "PUT";
                httpRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + ((UserCredential)driveService.HttpClientInitializer).Token.AccessToken;
                httpRequest.ContentLength = (long)cnt;
                httpRequest.Headers["Content-Range"] = string.Format("bytes {0}-{1}/{2}", bytesSent, bytesSent + cnt - 1, fileSize);

                using (System.IO.Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync().Result)
                {
                    requestStream.Write(temp, 0, cnt);
                }

                HttpWebResponse httpResponse;
                try
                {
                    httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
                }
                catch (WebException ex)
                {
                    httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                }

                if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                { }
                else if ((int)httpResponse.StatusCode != 308)
                    break;

                bytesSent += cnt;

                Console.WriteLine("Uploaded " + bytesSent.ToString());
            }

            if (bytesSent != uploadStream.Length)
            {
                return null;
            }

            // Try to retrieve the file from Google
            FilesResource.ListRequest request = driveService.Files.List();
            if (parents.Count > 0)
                request.Q += "'" + parents[0] + "' in parents and ";
            request.Q += "name = '" + destfilename + "'";
            FileList result = request.Execute();
            if (result.Files.Count > 0)
                uploadedFile = result.Files[0];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return uploadedFile;
    }
```

Comment: I very much doubt that this is required - `ResumableUpload` should handle this situation, just not with your existing code. I'll have a look today, although I'll use the storage API as a simpler example of using `ResumableUpload`.

Comment: As I mentioned above, this is just needed when we create restful API

Comment: We cannot upload all file data at a time when we are using Restful that is relaying between program and Google API.

Comment: By "storage API" I mean "The Google Cloud Storage REST API" - so the equivalent of the Drive API, but for Google Cloud Storage. I've looked at this in a bit more detail, and `ResumableUpload` itself doesn't support *manual* chunking - but it should handle any errors for you. What errors did you have when you just tried to upload the stream in the obvious way?

Comment: As you see above code, I don't use raw HttpWebRequest for creating Session.
That's because, I had 401 UnAuthorized error if I use raw HttpWebRequest when creating InitiateSession. 
Actually, I wanted to use this way, but still not solved that issue. However, I don't have any other issue for current code.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you've brought HttpWebRequest into it... the point of ResumableUpload is that you shouldn't need to do this chunking yourself. So could you show what you tried and explain what went wrong, so we can try to work out what the problem was?

Comment: It seems that you don't still understand me.
Lets assume that you need to create Restful MVC API using ASP.NET.
then you will need at least following apis.
- Create Session
- Upload Chunk // uploading chunk by chunk is must because, we are uploading large files.

But, as you know, there is no chunk upload function in Google drive api sdk, so I used HttpWebRequest.

Does this make sense?

FYI: the code i uploaded is just test code that will be imported to API Code

Comment: Ah, so it's not that you actually want to upload a whole stream, which you have in your test code in the question - you don't actually *have* all the data when you start the upload? That might affect things anyway, given that the ResumableUpload class does different things depending on whether or not it can determine the length to start with. If the real question is about uploading in chunks - potentially from different servers - that's a different question really. We could definitely consider that use case for the API, though I can't promise anything.

Comment: I've read your question several times, and it's only just started becoming clear to me - partly because your test code is misleading. It doesn't test the situation you'll actually be in... you're creating a `ResumableUpload` with a complete stream, but you wouldn't actually have a complete stream. I'll file an issue on github referring to this as a feature request.

Comment: Filed https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1076 - but please note that this set of client libraries is in maintenance mode; we're not looking to add more features regularly.